# Can anyone identify what sort of wordpress plugin is this?

Tags: wordpress

I am a beginner wordpress developer and I want to know what is the plugin in the following site:

http://nextgencrm.in/

The plugin i wish to know about is the one where the numbers display in the circle and first it starts from zero and then it starts increasing to the desired value...I am a beginner so excuse me if this is an illogical question...

Comment: It's not so much a plugin as it is some JavaScript that runs when the page loads. It appears to use the code from another Stack Overflow question [https://stackoverflow.com/a/35606739/387843](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35606739/387843)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a plugin that can be used :- https://wordpress.org/plugins/skt-skill-bar/
This is a plugin that displays the required skill value in terms of bars and circle but in percentage forms.
The numbers start from 0 to the required value and you can assign different colours to each skills.
Other plugin that can be used is - https://wordpress.org/plugins/wen-skill-charts/ .

Answer (score 0):

It's not a plugin. it's feature of the theme they're using.
The name of the theme is Alaska.

[Alaska - SEO WHMCS Hosting, Shop, Business Theme](https://themeforest.net/item/alaska-seo-whmcs-hosting-shop-business-theme/10068801)

It is implemented by jQuery. you can find it here:

http://nextgencrm.in/wp-content/themes/alaska/assets/js/jquery.countTo.js?ver=1.0.0.0